# Loging in on an RMI server

Tags: java, rmi, multiplayer

I am trying to implement a 2-player game that can be played over a network by means of RMI. I have a `Game` interface and a `GameImpl` class that implements the interface. In order to allow a client to play one game, I have a server class that looks as follows:

```
public class RMIServer {

    public RMIServer(int port) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        Game game = new GameImpl();
        registry.bind("Game", game);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
        RMIServer server = new RMIServer(1099);
    }

}
```

The client class on the other hand looks as follows:

```
public class RMIClient {

    RMIClient(String host, int port) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port);
        Game game = (Game) registry.lookup("Game");
        game.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        RMIClient client = new RMIClient("127.0.0.1", 1099);
    }

}
```

This implementation works well if only one player needs to play the game over a network. The problem that I'm having now is that I want to make a login so that two different players can play against each other over the network. The main problem is that I don't really know where to go to with the possible users and all their games and how I can check their login.

I thought about keeping a `Map<User, Game>` in the server and registering the correct game if the user is logged in, but I have no idea how to do the login then or how to make sure the client gets to the right game.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering exactly the same questions when I developed my [2-player minesweeper game](https://github.com/stephanebruckert/JMines) using RMI. First you have to wonder how you want the games to be created?

1. Would you like to create a game between the first 2 available players ("play ASAP" mode)? Example:

   ```
   - player1 connects
   - player2 connects
   - the server automatically starts a game between player1 and player2
   ```
2. Would you like the players to choose their opponent (saloon)? Example:

   ```
   - player1 connects
   - player2 connects
   - player3 connects
   - player1 decides to start a game with player3
   ```

---

If you decide to go with the second mode, here is one way to go.

On the server, keep a list with the currently connected players. Every time a client connects to the server and successfully logs in, add him to that list:

```
/** The connected players */
private List<Player> connectedPlayers;
```

Also prepare a map with the game instance associated by each player (by the way, you were on the right track!).

```
/** The games currently being played */
private Map<Player, Game> gameList;
```

When a game is created between two players (player1 wants to play with player2), add them to the game list.

```
Game game = new Game(player1, player2);
this.gameList.put(player1, game);
this.gameList.put(player2, game);
```

If you need to know if a user is available and not already in a game:

```
public boolean isUserAvailable(String potentialOpponent) throws RemoteException {
    for (Entry<Player, Game> entry : this.gameList.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().getUsername().equals(potentialOpponent)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the game is over, remove the 2 players from the map.

```
this.gameList.remove(game.getPlayerHost());
this.gameList.remove(game.getPlayerClient());
```

---

I won't be able to copy/paste more code here, but if you need inspiration you can find the [source code](https://github.com/stephanebruckert/JMines) to my game. These files are interesting:

- [src/server/controller/Dispatcher.java](https://github.com/stephanebruckert/JMines/blob/master/src/server/controller/Dispatcher.java)
- [src/client/controller/Receiver.java](https://github.com/stephanebruckert/JMines/blob/master/src/client/controller/Receiver.java)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're tackling this on an extremely low level.  Unless you have very good reason you should consider using a higher level of abstraction such as...

1. [Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) and optionally also [Spring Security Remoting RMI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/remoting/rmi/package-summary.html)
2. [Enterprise JavaBeans](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/ejb/index.html)
3. [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/rmi.html)

These technologies will allow you to continue using RMI as your **transport** but also easily build **components** using the [Session Facade](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/sessionfacade-141285.html).

It would be very tedious to do this all on your own.

---

To clarify my answer a bit.  You should store your game object using the Session Facade Pattern.

This is your central question...

> I have no idea how to do the login then or how to make sure the client gets to the right game.

And it is a deceptively complicated one.

1. "How to do the login" is an implementation of an account service ( complete with tokens/cookies )
2. "How to make sure the client gets the right game" is an implementation of a *Session Scope* that can keep your game objects and return it to the user that presents the correct tokens/credentials.

Comment: Though this is an extremley good point to mention, but, in the real sense, this isn't an answer for OP's question.

Comment: @shekharsuman I've tried to clarify a bit.  But I don't think the only way to answer a question is by providing code.  I've listed 3 libraries that would do what the OP needs if he cares to pick one.